# Why is my instance variable undefined in HAML view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm not sure why I couldn't find this in the documentation or anywhere online, but if my controller is:

```
# HomeController
class HomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @var = "A Sample Variable"
   end
end
```

..and if my HAML view uses a haml layout and looks like this:

```
/ index.html.haml
%p "This is a paragraph"
%p
   = @var
```

...why is the instance variable @var is never shown? The paragraph is there but @var is always null. I know this because calling @var.split('') throws an undefined method error. The HAML version I'm using is 4.0.3. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `index` action will render `index.html.haml`, not `home.html.haml`. You're rendering the wrong view there.

Comment: Tried this but doesn't fix my issue. Maybe it's something small I missed because I'm just starting out with haml ?

Comment: Haml's very similar to ERB and follows the same rules - it's just a different markup style. Are you showing us the actual failing code, or is that a simplified example? You might have missed something in the actual code if that's not it.

Comment: That's the actual code, I wish I had left something out, it'd be easier to figure out. I've generated the controller using 'rails generate controller home' and the file I got was an .erb file. I used "html2haml" to change that file to a .haml file and then wrote the code I've displayed in the question

Comment: Okay, you were right, I had simplified the code. I was also including a module in the controller, and even though that didn't show any errors, it was breaking the instance variables. I can't believe it really, but thanks! It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Change the view file name to `index.html.haml` as that's the action you have your instance variable defined under. Or alternatvely you can add a home action to your controller and store the var instance variable there, so the home template has access to it

Comment: I did this. Doesn't seem to fix it. This is probably something very small that I missed, maybe I didn't install haml correctly, or I don't know. At this point I'm just starting to learn haml so there's a good chance I missed something obvious to most people.